# Grails - How to execute a javascript method after a template is rendered?

Tags: grails, gsp

I'm trying to execute a javascript code to initialize certain components in my gsp template. I need the script code to be executed after the template is loaded. The template is loaded from a controller. Any idea how this can be achieved?

Code to render the template within the controler:

```
render(template: 'myTemplate', model:[user:User])
```

I'm using formRemote to call the controller

```
<g:formRemote url="[action:'showMeTemplate', controller: 'User']" name= "formName" update="myTemplateDiv">
</g:formRemote>
```

Comment: have you tried the `onSuccess` or `onComplete` events on the `formRemote` ? http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/formRemote.html

Comment: It was onComplete. My bad, did not notice that in documentation. I was trying with before and after. Can someone mark this as an answer?

Comment: i'll convert it to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `onSuccess` or `onComplete` events on the `formRemote` tag.

See http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/formRemote.html

Answer (score 0):

you could make use of the "before" attribute

```
<g:formRemote before="setTimeout(function(){return true;},500);" url="[action:'showMeTemplate', controller: 'User']" name= "formName" update="myTemplateDiv" >
</g:formRemote>
```

didnt test it, but maybe you get an idea

Answer (score 0):

From the Grails docs (http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Tags/formRemote.html) you can use the `onLoaded` parameter to call some JavaScript if the remote form call succeeds (i.e. if the remote form can be rendered):

```
<g:formRemote url="[action:'showMeTemplate', controller: 'User']" name= "formName" update="myTemplateDiv" onLoaded ="myJSfunction()">
</g:formRemote>
```